# PL/SQL ROWNUM keyword and equality (=)

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I am new in PL/SQL and I am trying the **ROWNUM** keyword.

If I query this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

I am getting a result. Even in this case:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

But if I try

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ROWNUM = 2
```

I get an empty result..

But the table `my_table`has more than one tuple.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30321788/3989608 I have covered most of the things about ROWNUM in this answer.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question

Answer (score 1):

ROWNUM is a psuedo column that has a value AFTER the result set is returned.  Thus you can use `where rownum < 2` but you can't select where ROWNUM equals a value because it does not have a value to compare to yet.