# SQL Server : Top 1 query to Oracle (11g) not 12c

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

Here is a single SQL statement in SQL Server

```
SELECT 
    a.EMPNUM,
    (SELECT TOP 1 NAMEKO 
     FROM PA0001 
     WHERE COMPCD = a.COMPCD 
       AND EMPNUM = a.LASTUP 
     ORDER BY EDDATE DESC) AS LASTNM,
    (SELECT TOP 1 NAMEKO 
     FROM PA0001 
     WHERE COMPCD = a.COMPCD 
       AND EMPNUM = a.FRSTUP 
     ORDER BY EDDATE DESC) AS FIRSNM
FROM PA0000 a
```

Then, I tried to apply it to Oracle 11g (not Oracle 12c which supports the top n query)

```
SELECT 
    empnum,  
    (SELECT NAMEKO 
     FROM 
          (SELECT NAMEKO 
           FROM PA0001 
           WHERE COMPCD = a.COMPCD 
             AND EMPNUM = a.FRSTUP 
           ORDER BY EDDATE DESC) 
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS FRSTNM,  
    (SELECT NAMEKO 
     FROM 
          (SELECT NAMEKO 
           FROM PA0001 
           WHERE COMPCD = a.COMPCD 
             AND EMPNUM = a.LASTUP 
           ORDER BY EDDATE DESC) 
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS LASTNM
FROM PA0000 a
```

Then I got an error

> ORA-00904: "A"."FRSTUP": invalid identifier.

How can I rewrite the query for Oracle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select range of rows in Oracle, excluding the rownum field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321483/select-range-of-rows-in-oracle-excluding-the-rownum-field)

Comment: You will get your complete answer about how to use ROWNUM in the post marked as duplicate.

Comment: I made a function to use "execute immediate " and apply it to the query, thanks folks.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add alias "a" to table `PA0000` to avoid error `ORA-00904: "A"."FRSTUP": invalid identifier.`

Answer (score 1):

using rownum=1 will select a random value not dependent on the order by clause (rather how the blocks are aligned on disk)

12c has this feature ( **FETCH FIRST {n} ROWS ONLY** clause )

In 11.2 and less,  using **row_number ()** is the most convenient way

Example of selecting the the latest object (single) created in the schema:

```
select *
  from (select user_objects.object_name,
               user_objects.object_id,
               user_objects.created,
               row_number () over (order by user_objects.created desc) as rn
          from user_objects) view_uo
 where view_uo.rn = 1
```

Viewing the latest 10 objects would be  **rn <= 10**

Then just modify this to include your selects.

Comment: It's not **LIMIT BY**, it's `FETCH FIRST n ROWS`. And yes you could do pagination using ROWNUM, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30321788/3989608

Comment: Correct,  I was thinking of mysql.  Haven't yet had any 12c in my production environment.  Will update the answer

Comment: Also with rownum, you have to know how it works to use it correctly.  I have used it before, but I find that row_number() is more explicit and understandable for people unsure of (or new to) Oracle SQL.  It's very easy to misunderstand how rownum works and get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your question you can achieve the result by using `level, connect by prior` as follows:

```
SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP WHERE HIREDATE IN
(SELECT MAX(HIREDATE) FROM EMP WHERE LEVEL<=1 CONNECT BY PRIOR HIREDATE>HIREDATE GROUP BY LEVEL) ORDER BY HIREDATE DESC;
```

Hope this will solve your requirement...