# PLSQL Error when trying to insert record

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am getting this error when i try to insert data through my procedure:

```
Error starting at line : 48 in command -
BEGIN
  OPEN_CLASS('PRAC_4', 'ISYS224', 'Tue', '09:00', 'P', 'E6A123');
END;
Error report -
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at "43053327.OPEN_CLASS", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 2
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

My procedure at the moment is (Works fine with all other tests iv run so far):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OPEN_CLASS(
    p_class IN TUTPRAC.CLASSID%TYPE,
    p_unitc IN TUTPRAC.UNITCODE%TYPE,
    p_classd IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_DAY%TYPE,
    p_classt IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TIME%TYPE,
    p_classtp IN TUTPRAC.CLASS_TYPE%TYPE,
    p_roomnm IN TUTPRAC.ROOMNUM%TYPE)

    IS

    -- Variables    
    x number:=0;
    y number:=0;  
    CLASS_OVERLAPS EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
    -- checks
    SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 FROM TUTPRAC WHERE UNITCODE = p_unitc and CLASS_DAY = p_classd or CLASS_DAY = p_classd and CLASS_TIME = p_classt and ROOMNUM = p_roomnm) , 0) INTO x FROM dual;
    SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 FROM UNITSTREAM WHERE UNITCODE = p_unitc and DAY = p_classd or DAY = p_classd and TIME = p_classt and LOCATION = p_roomnm) , 0) INTO y FROM dual;

    -- insert
    IF (x = 0 and y = 0) THEN
      INSERT INTO TUTPRAC (CLASSID, UNITCODE, CLASS_DAY, CLASS_TIME, CLASS_TYPE, ROOMNUM) 
      VALUES (p_class, p_unitc, p_classd, p_classt, p_classtp, p_roomnm);
    ELSE
       RAISE CLASS_OVERLAPS;
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN CLASS_OVERLAPS
      THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'The class you have tried to insert is clashing with an existing class.');

END OPEN_CLASS;
```

My procedure checks to see if the class record being inserted clashes with any classes already in the table. This procedure has worked for every test case i'v tried so far except for this one.

Comment: Looks like the first SELECT statement at line 18 returns more than one row, so the SELECT INTO statement raises an exception.

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli its `select 1 ` how its returnng more then row ? I guess the issue with NVL

Comment: How would i fix this ? allow the statement to return more than 1 row ? @MarcoBaldelli

Comment: @Moudiz "*its select 1 how its returnng more then row ?*" What does that mean? SELECT `1` doesn't mean it would return single row, it would just return the value 1 against each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at "43053327.OPEN_CLASS", line 18
```

The error is due to the fact that your **SELECT .. INTO** statement gives multiple rows, however, it should generate only a single row.

Execute the **SQL** without INTO clause to check the number of rows returned, and put the required filer. If you want to pick a single row, then you could limit the rows to `1` using **ROWNUM**.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 FROM TUTPRAC WHERE UNITCODE = p_unitc 
and CLASS_DAY = p_classd or CLASS_DAY = p_classd 
and CLASS_TIME = p_classt and ROOMNUM = p_roomnm) , 0) FROM dual
);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 FROM UNITSTREAM WHERE UNITCODE = p_unitc 
and DAY = p_classd or DAY = p_classd and TIME = p_classt 
and LOCATION = p_roomnm) , 0) FROM dual
);
```

`SELECT 1` doesn't mean it would return a single row, it would just return the value `1` for every row fetched. If you want to restrict the number of rows, then:

- **[ROWNUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321483/how-rownum-works-in-pagination-query/30321788#30321788)**
- Row-limiting feature **FETCH** in **12c**.

---

**UPDATE**

Per OP's comment below, **COUNT** is needed.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO x 
FROM TUTPRAC 
WHERE UNITCODE = p_unitc 
AND CLASS_DAY = p_classd or CLASS_DAY = p_classd 
AND CLASS_TIME = p_classt and ROOMNUM = p_roomnm;

SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO y     
FROM UNITSTREAM 
WHERE UNITCODE = p_unitc 
AND DAY = p_classd or DAY = p_classd 
AND TIME = p_classt and LOCATION = p_roomnm;
```

Comment: Does this increment my X and Y variables ? because i am using those to check for clashes if X and/or Y are > 0 then the record will not insert into the table @Lalit Kumar B

Comment: @CM25 I think you need to use **COUNT** instead of **1**.

Comment: These seems good, but i get the error `Error(22,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` AND `Error(29,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` when i try to run the script. @Lalit Kumar B I am using Oracle SQL Developer for reference.

Comment: @CM25 Corrected the query. Please mark it as answered, would help others too.