# In different rownum selection same result in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination, rownum

I am trying to paginate my page,

I am using this query :

```
Select *
From   (
  Select Row_.*,
         Rownum Rownum_
  From   (
    Select Distinct(Qa.Question_Id) As Id
    From   Question Qa
    Where  Qa.Is_Deleted = 'F'
    And    Qa.Is_Answered = 'T'
    Order By Qa.Like_Count Desc
  ) Row_ 
  Where Rownum <= 10
) Where Rownum_ > 0
```

My result is

```
10662   1
11315   2
11142   3
13591   4
12344   5
12264   6
12186   7
11938   8
11183   9
10842   10
```

When i am trying to paginate in 5 max result solution is

```
Select *
From   (
  Select Row_.*,
         Rownum Rownum_
  From   (
    Select Distinct(Qa.Question_Id) As Id
    From   Question Qa
    Where  Qa.Is_Deleted = 'F'
    And    Qa.Is_Answered = 'T'
    Order By Qa.Like_Count Desc
  ) Row_ 
  Where Rownum <= 5
) Where Rownum_ > 0
```

Result :

```
10662   1
11315   2
11142   3
11183   4
10842   5
```

And:

```
Select *
From   (
  Select Row_.*,
         Rownum Rownum_
  From   (
    Select Distinct(Qa.Question_Id) As Id
    From   Question Qa
    Where  Qa.Is_Deleted = 'F'
    And    Qa.Is_Answered = 'T'
    Order By Qa.Like_Count Desc
  ) Row_ 
  Where Rownum <= 10
) Where Rownum_ > 5
```

Result

```
12264   6
12186   7
11938   8
11183   9
10842   10
```

In second and third script, Solution in third script 9,10 rownum is equal with second script 4,5.

Why the solution is not like the first query? How can i paginate my query properly?

Comment: Maybe the same question than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321483/how-rownum-works-in-pagination-query)?

Comment: As an aside - `DISTINCT` is a keyword which applies across all columns that are selected and is **not** a function (as you appear to be formatting your code to try to make it appear to be).

Comment: @Aleksej Not a duplicate as the linked question is asking how to do pagination (and several other clarifications about `ROWNUM` which would have been better separating into different questions) whereas this one is asking "Why is it not working after using what is the accepted method is that linked question?".

Comment: @MT0 , i solved my issue like this ->  Order By Qa.Like_Count Desc, qa.id. Qa.id is uniqe and it is ordering without any problem. Thanks a lot for help.