# Oracle sql rownum between how to shrink the query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pagination

I would like to get records from 25 to 50. I write this code, but, it looks terrible with double select clause.

```
Select * From (
    Select eto.*, rownum rn from employee_trip_orders eto
) where rn between 25 and 50 ;
```

How can i shrink it to use one select like that?

```
 Select eto.*, eto.rownum rn from employee_trip_orders eto
 where rn between 25 and 50 ;
```

I don't need the second one. Thanks. I have old 11c Oracle version and offset keyword is not suitting me

Comment: You simply can't. The first query is the only way

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use  sub-query ?

Comment: Use this query also   select  all_coloumns_name,rn
form (
Select eto.*, rownum rn 
  from employee_trip_orders eto)
 where rn<= 25 and rn<= 50 ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i shrink it to use one select like that?

Since you are on Oracle `11g` you cannot. You must use subquery inline to achieve your desired output.

> ```
> Select eto.*, eto.rownum rn from employee_trip_orders eto
> where rn between 25 and 50 ;
> ```

That query will never return a row. **ROWNUM** value is incremented only after it is assigned. Please see [How ROWNUM works in pagination query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30321788/3989608).

From Oracle 12c onwards, you could use the new [Top-n Row limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29411029/3989608) feature.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `order by` clause so what is the meaning of the `rownum`? In the end, You are only fetching **random 26 (25-50 inclusive) records**.

So You can achieve the desired result using the following code:

```
Select eto.*, rownum rn 
  from employee_trip_orders eto
 where rownum<= 26 ;
```

Cheers!!